# 'subl' command stopped working in zsh

Tags: macos, zsh

When I try to create a file from the command line I get the error zsh: command not found: “open

This was working and stopped a few days ago :(  In my .zshrc file the shortcut is: `alias subl=“open -a 'Sublime Text'”`

my $PATH is: `/Users/joe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin:/Users/joe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/bin:/Users/joe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/joe/.rvm/bin:/Users/joe/.rvm/bin`

Any ideas what I need to do to get my alias working again?

Comment: Barmar's answer worked

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using curly quotes in your alias command. Shells only use ASCII single quotes and double quotes. Change `“` and `”` to `"`:

```
alias subl="open -a 'Sublime Text'"
```

Don't use a word processor when editing shell scripts, use a programming text editor like `emacs` or `vi`, and they won't convert traditional quotes into curly quotes.

Comment: Thank you Barmar!  I edited the file using nano.  I do not have enough reputation to upvote yet.

Comment: You don't need to upvote answers to your own question. Click on the check mark to accept the answer.